# Automating the mobile browser on Android with Appium

Tags: android, testing, selenium, appium

I am writing a simple test to navigate to a website on a mobile browser, mostly to get an understanding of Appium. I am using an android emulator. My code looks like this:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileBrowserType;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.URL;

public class DLMobileTest
{
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void loadingSinglePageTest() throws Exception{
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 7");
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", MobileBrowserType.BROWSER);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org");
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the emulator's browser briefly starts, but before it navigates to the Wikipedia site I'm aiming for, I get this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Did not get session redirect from Chromedriver) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

I'm not sure what my mistake is here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

add app in desired capability like 
capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome");

Comment: Doesn't work, I'm afraid. I'm still getting the SessionNotCreatedException. And now the browser doesn't even open anymore as it did before.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities  capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
     capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome");
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "5.0");
     capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","TA9330FZ02");
     capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS")

Comment: with this capability i am able to open chrome in my device

Comment: Sorry, it's still not working for me. I copy pasted your suggestion, changing only the device name to fit my device, but I still get the same error. Maybe there is a problem on the virtual device I'm using regarding Chrome. Since I need to use the Android Standard Browser for my tests anyway, is there a way to use that instead of Chrome? I tried substituting "Chrome" with "Android" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, btw.

Comment: Just want to add, I was able to open the Android standard browser with the code in the OP, but it crashed before it could navigate to the desired website.

Comment: I get the same issues and spent maybe a day trying different recommendations littered online. Sucks there is not a standard example for Appium/Android/Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I understand by now you would have got a solution for your question. But this is for the sake of people like me looking for an answer to the same question above. I tired using

```
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
```

instead of

```
capabilities.setCapability("browserName", MobileBrowserType.BROWSER);
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same problem.  In appium installation directory chromedriver.exe file will be there.  Replace that file with the latest version of it.  This solved the problem for me.  Let me know if you need more detailed answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an sample code for installing chrome from apk, you can try out different options to test as requirement, the apk is automatically installed, make sure the code and apk are in the same path.

```
    import os

    import unittest
    from appium import webdriver


    # Returns absoute path relative to this file and not cwd
    PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p)
    )
    class SimpleAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
            desired_caps = {}
    #Specify platform below(Android, iOS)
            desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
    #Specify OS version(Settings->About phone -> android version)
            desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.0.1'
    #Obtain the Device name from Adb[For Android](Terminal Command: "adb devices")
            desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'TA93400A78'
    #Specify the path to Application
            desired_caps['app'] = PATH('Chrome-com.android.chrome-2171093-v39.0.2171.93.apk')

            self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

        def tearDown(self):
            # end the session
            self.driver.quit()


        def test_open_chrome(self):
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.chrome:id/terms_accept").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            for i in range(0,3):
                self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.chrome:id/positive_button").click()
                self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.android.chrome:id/menu_button").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("New incognito tab").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("Bookmarks").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("Recent tabs").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("History").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("Bookmarks").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back() 
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("Settings").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_elements_by_name("com.android.chrome:id/header_title").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_name("Help & feedback").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            self.driver.back()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)






    if __name__ == '__main__':
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleAndroidTests)
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question; they want to drive the stock android browser without it crashing, they aren't interested in the google chrome browser app. Remember that the term "Chrome" doesn't necessarily refer to the google chrome browser.